# Is it possible to union results in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to union tables aggregated from different queries and return the whole result set from a stored procedure. Here is what I mean:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invalid_pa() RETURNS TABLE (p_id int) AS $$
DECLARE
    pl int[] := ARRAY(SELECT id FROM p.pl);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(platforms, 1)
    LOOP
          --The query is SELECT id FROM dblink(connection_str(i), 'Some query')
          --I need to union all the query above
          --and return the unioned table
    END LOOP;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I union different result sets in such a way?

`connection_str(i)` here is a stored procedure returning the actual connection string

Comment: yes, use dynamic SQL (execute $s$ select * from $s$||tanlename||$s$ union .....$s$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things amiss with your posted code, but ignoring those the solution would be somewhat like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invalid_pa() RETURNS TABLE (p_id int) AS $$
DECLARE
  pl int[] := ARRAY(SELECT id FROM p.pl); -- ???
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(platforms, 1) -- platforms???
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT id FROM dblink(connection_str(i), 'Some query');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`RETURN QUERY` adds zero or more rows to the result set and the final `RETURN` returns the entire result set to the caller. Effectively, the results from all the `dblink` calls are `UNION`ed together.